# Как из csv файла вывести существующие строки

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть очень много строк такого формата

```
header1;header2;header3
text;text;text
text;NaN;text
text;text;NaN
```

Мне нужно вывести header2 и header3 только если они не равны NaN как мне это сделать?

Попробовал что то вроде этого

```
import pandas as pd
ps = pd.read_csv('3.csv', sep=';', encoding='Windows-1251')
a = ps.dropna()
print(a)
```

но удаляет всё кроме заголовков

Comment: А в оконцовке Вам что нужно удалить поля или записи?

Comment: Мне нужно вывести все строки из большого файла в которых есть и заголовок2 и заголовок3

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе тот вывод, который вы хотите получить? Иначе непонятно что именно вы пытаетесь сделать

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что не проглядели вывод? Вот Ваш файл:

```
$ cat 3.csv 
header1;header2;header3
text;text;text
text;NaN;text
text;text;NaN
```

Вот Ваша программа (убрал только параметр кодировки):

```
$ cat test.py 
import pandas as pd
ps = pd.read_csv('3.csv', sep=';')
a = ps.dropna()
print(a)
```

А вот результаты её работы:

```
$ python test.py 
  header1 header2 header3
0    text    text    text
```

Не вижу никаких проблем.

Comment: Да проблема вывода была в величине файла после указания заголовка после 'ps' в переменной 'a' стало выводить, но вопрос остаётся открытым 
`
a = ps['text'].dropna()
`
выводит мне 2 заголовок, но как вывести сразу 2-й и 3-й вместе?

Comment: Честно говоря - ничего не понял! "проблема вывода была в величине файла" - это вообще - о чём?!

Comment: Когда я использовал свой код у меня выводились только заголовки, но когда я сделал
`
a = ps['BSSID'].dropna()
`
То у меня стали выводиться именно строки